# Program crashes after output

Tags: c++, sigabrt

I am trying to run a program and SOMETIMES I'm getting this error when trying to compile

ld returned 1 exit status

Although, when it compiles (like I said, not always) and trying to put certain input, the program outputs the answer... and then crashes. Is there any way is this possible at all?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  bool flag;
  int n,x[] = {1,-1};
  long long int A,cont,mul,acum;
  while(cin >> n >> A) {
    acum = 0;
    vector<long long int> nums(n),nums2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin >> nums[i];

    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());

    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
      flag = 1;
      for(int j=0;j<i and flag;j++) if(nums[i]%nums[j] == 0) flag = 0;
      if(flag) nums2.push_back(nums[i]);
    }

    n = nums2.size();

    vector<long long int> mult(n,0);

    const long long int num = (1<<n);
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
      cont = 0, mul = 1;
      for(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--) if(i & (1<<j)) cont++, mul *= nums2[j];
      mult[cont-1] += A/mul;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) acum += (x[i%2]*mult[i]);

    cout << acum << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the input I put when the program crashes:

```
17 1000
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: what message do you receive on crash ?

Comment: @hinafu, as a sidenote you forgot to `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: The compiler errors sometimes could be the result of some not supporting `and` as `&&`.

Comment: [It compiles okay on gcc-4.3.4 and runs successfully](http://ideone.com/Zc6Ji)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your program in a debugger, you'll see that the problem occurs on the line

```
mult[cont-1] += A/mul;
```

when cont is 0, which means that you are trying to modify element -1 of the vector.

I can't tell what the algorithm is trying to do, so I can't tell why cont might end up zero.

Overall advice: Learn to use a debugger. It's your friend. :)

Comment: but I'm still confused, why the program outputs the answer when the output line is after the line where the problem is (was)

Comment: You don't say what compiler you are using, but you are probably compiling your program optimized and not debug. Probably your STL libraries don't do vector bounds checking in optimized mode, which means that instead of crashing on the line above, it just silently corrupts memory. The corruption show itself until all the objects are being destructed at the end of the program. Almost always you want to get your program going using debug compilation and only switch to optimized when you are finished and need the extra speed.